# applescript with javascript -> get string from href

Tags: javascript, applescript, href

I try to read out the string inside of an unordered list .

The string of interest is the following number: `href="?notation=1549220"` 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi5Q1.jpg)

I am very new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript so please excuse this simple question.

I tried something like this, but it's getting nowhere:

```
document.getElementById('exchangesLayerHs')
  .getElementsByTagName('ul')
  .getElementsByTagName('li')
  .getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Has anyone a tipp for me?

Thanks a lot!
Carlo

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you posted your entire AppleScript rather than just the JavaScript snippet

Answer (score 1):

You could get the link with the title *handelsplatz geschlossen* :

```
var link = document.querySelector("a [title='Handelsplatz geschlossen']");
```

Now simply get the thing behind *=* in the *href* and convert it to a number (*+*) :

```
var result = + link.href.split("=")[1];
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your quick response!  I tried to include your proposal into my applescript as follows:  `set link to do JavaScript "document.querySelector('a [title='Handelsplatz geschlossen']');" in document 1`  But when I try to `log link` then I get an error message "'link' is not defined". What do I do wrong?

Comment: @carloP i cant help you with apple script... Sorry

Comment: By the way, the tag <a> with title="Handelsplatz geschlossen" is not unique, there are multiple of these tags in the unordered list <ul>. Is this the reason why I maybe could not reach it just by the title?

Comment: @carloP then you need querySelectorAll(...)[4] to get e.g. the fourth one. However, the error you get is related to applescript